# Sorting by number of answers

Tags: feature-request, sorting

Why isn't it a tab for sorting by the number of answers that a question has?

Comment: Not sure what the use case would be for this -- maybe it's worth elaborating why you'd want to?

Comment: It would be some sort of a measure of knowledge-popularity about the question... and easier to find and answer questions with few answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the search shake its tail feather for you and query for questions based on the minimum answers posted.

If you wanted to see questions tagged **`[jquery]`** with at least five (5) answers:

> [[jquery] answers:5](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bjquery%5d%20answers%3a5)

If you wanted at least 15 answers:

> [[jquery] answers:15](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bjquery%5d%20answers%3a15)

Comment: +1 for this, I knew about it, but nonetheless, it's a useful answer for other users that might be wondering how to do that. However, it doesn't answer my question as to why there isn't a tab for that.

Comment: Oh definitely doesn't answer your question, but comes as close.

Comment: This is a pretty cool url hack - but IMHO should have appropriate widgets to control it.